# How to write a subquery in yii2 'where'?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I have this query:

```
select * from dias_clases as dc
inner join clases as cl on cl.clase_id = dc.clase
inner join asistencias as asis on asis.dia_clase = dc.dc_id
where( 
clase in(select ce.clase from clases_estudiantes as ce where ce.estudiante = 321)
or dc_id in (select cr.dia_clase from clase_recuperada as cr where cr.estudiante = 321)
)
and fecha < '2017-04-26'
and cl.disciplina = 9
and dc.estado = 1
group by dc.dc_id
order by dc.fecha desc
```

It works fine in the mysql console. I need the same query in Yii2 with the active record and i got this:

```
$dias_clases = DiasClases::find()
                ->innerJoin("clases as cl", "cl.clase_id = clase")
                ->leftJoin("asistencias as asis", "asis.dia_clase = dc_id")
                ->where("
                    clase in(
                        select ce.clase from clases_estudiantes as ce where ce.estudiante = :estudiante
                    )
                    or dc_id in (
                        select cr.dia_clase from clase_recuperada as cr where cr.estudiante = :estudiante
                    )", [":estudiante" => $estudiante->estudiante_id]
                )
                ->andWhere("fecha < :fecha", [":fecha" => $fecha])
                ->andWhere(["cl.disciplina" => $disciplina])
                ->andWhere(["estado" => DiasClases::TERMINADA])
                ->orderBy(["fecha" => SORT_DESC])
                ->all();
```

But the 'where' is not working properly. The results i get are wrong and i think it is because this part:

```
where( 
    clase in(select ce.clase from clases_estudiantes as ce where ce.estudiante = 321)
    or dc_id in (select cr.dia_clase from clase_recuperada as cr where cr.estudiante = 321)
    )
```

does'nt executes the same way that in console. The parenthesis is needed

Comment: Post the query you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the yii2 github project and ask directly and this was the answer they give and it works like a charm:

```
->where(['or', 
        [
            'in',
            'clase', 
            (new Query)
                ->select('ce.clase')
                ->from('clases_estudiantes')
                ->where(['estudiante' => $estudiante->estudiante_id])
        ],
        [
            'in', 
            'dc_id', 
            (new Query)
                ->select('dia_clase')
                ->from('clase_recuperada')
                ->where(['estudiante' => $estudiante->estudiante_id])
        ]

    ])
```

And this is the URL for you to check:
[Here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/14077#issuecomment-297911747)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a ClasesEstudiantes model for clases_estudiantes table for You could buil a subquery eg:

```
$subquery1 = ClasesEstudiantes::find()
      ->select('clase')->andWhere([ 'estudiante'>=  $estudiante])

DiasClases::find()
     ->innerJoin("clases as cl", "cl.clase_id = clase")
     ->leftJoin("asistencias as asis", "asis.dia_clase = dc_id")
     ->where('in', 'clase', $subquery1)
     .......

you can do the same for the other subquery  using `orWhere(   )`
```